# 2 sets of integration tests on Maven

Tags: maven-2

My maven project contains a few integration tests.
These tests are executed at the test phase. This happens in Hudson on every submit.

My wish is to add another set of integration tests, but I don't them to be executed on every build.

This means that I will have 2 sets of integration tests, one set is triggered on each build, and one set would be executed by using a profile.

I thought about adding another test folder, but that causes compilation problems.

Do you have any idea on how to implement it?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a profile http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: My question is not about maven profiles. My question is about adding another test folder that would be triggered using a profile. The link you added does not talk about this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you said you wanted to use a profile. We do this using the surefire plugin in conjunction with profiles; it lets you specify tests to run, etc. - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Answer (score 1):

First if you project has integration test than the have to be executed in the integration-test phase and *not* in the test phase. You have to use the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/plugin-info.html) instead of maven-surefire-plugin. Naming convention for unit tests is *Test.java, *TestCase.java etc. but for integration tests *IT.java or *ITCase.java etc. Details can be found in the docs of maven-surefire or maven-failsafe-plugin.

The best solution for your problem is to have separate modules (multi-module build)

```
 +-- root
      +-- project-a
      +-- mod-it1
      +-- mod-it2
```

whereas mod-it2 can be activated via a profile.